# Power reserve calculation for site_types

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have posted before but the codes were not shown properly. I am trying to write a logic to calculate the power reserve at telecom sites such as microwave stations and substations,...
I have created a site_type scaffold with following migration in the database mysql

mysql

```
id site_type

1 Substation
2 Generating Station
3 District Office 4 VHF_UHF Repeater
5 Capacitor Station
6 Office
7 Microwave Station
```

here is the site model

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lat, :long, :site_code, :site_name, :site_type, :site_type_id

  def is_microwave?
     self.site_type = 'Microwave Station'
  end

  def is_under_capacity?(capacity)
    (is_microwave? && capacity < 24) || (!is_microwave? && capacity < 8)
  end
```

the code in the viewer

```
- total_capacity = @site.dc_power_inventories.sum {|d| d.dc_power_supply.battery.capacity.capacity } rescue 0
- total_amps = @site.equipment_inventories.sum {|e| e.equipment.amp.amp } rescue 0
- capacity_left = (total_capacity.to_f / total_amps).round(2) rescue 0
div.row-fluid
  h4
    span Site Name: #{@site.site_code}
    span.pull-right Capacity Reserve Left: #{capacity_left}

  / h4 = "Capacity Reserve Left:  #{capacity_left} Hrs "

- if @site.is_under_capacity?(capacity_left)
  div.alert
    strong Warning !!!
    span         You Must add or replace the DC power system.
```

The issue I am having is that I only get the warning when sites (microwave or others) are under capacity (< 24 hrs). What I want is to get the warning for microwave site type when the capacity goes below 24 hrs and warning for other sites for < 8 hrs under reserve capacity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be wrong, but I think your test for Microwave is wrong, think you have missed out an = sign

```
  def is_microwave?
     self.site_type == 'Microwave Station'
  end
```